# Triangle inequality for subtraction?

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, triangles

Why is $|a - b| \geq|a| - |b|$?

Comment: it would be also nice to see an intuitive explanation/answer to this. It feels it should be obvious, no?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reverse Triangle Inequality Proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/127372/reverse-triangle-inequality-proof)

Answer (score 67, accepted):

It's sometimes called the reverse triangle inequality. The proper form is
$$\left| a - b \right| \ge \big||a| - |b|\big|$$
For the proof, consider
$$|a| = |a - b + b| \le |a - b| + |b|$$
$$|b| = |b - a + a| \le |a - b| + |a|$$
so that we have
$$-|a-b|\le|a|-|b| \le |a - b|$$

Comment: Let $s_n$ be a sequence. Is this valid then: $|s_n - s| < 1 \iff ||s_n| - |s|| < 1 \iff |s_n| < |s| + 1$?

Comment: That is indeed valid. You don't even need the reverse triangle inequality. $$|s_n| = |s_n - s + s| \le |s_n -s | + |s| < |s| + 1$$

Comment: Is this true for all norms?

Comment: @SPRajagopal The only property we used in the proof was the triangle inequality itself, so this holds with any norm.

Comment: is there an intuitive explanation for why this is true?

Comment: @CharlieParker It depends on what you mean by intuitive. The statement is a formalization of the fact that "the difference of two sides of a triangle is always less than (or equal to) the third side". I don't know if you find that fact intuitive or not, but it is just a restatement of the fact that "the sum of two sides of a triangle is always greater (or equal to) the third side", which is the triangle inequality itself. This is of course reflected in the fact that the reverse triangle inequality is a direct consequence of the triangle inequality.

Comment: Finally a good answer with a good proof, you'd think it would be more common on this site. Thank you!

Answer (score 18):

No. For example, $|(-2)-3|=5>|-2|-|3|=-1.$

I think you're thinking of $||a|-|b||\le |a- b|.$

Answer (score 10):

The length of any side of a triangle is greater than the absolute difference of the lengths of the other two sides:

$$||a|-|b||\leq |a-b|$$

Here is a proof:

$$|a+(b-a)|\leq |a|+|b-a|$$

and,

(1) $$|a-b|\geq |a|-|b|$$

Interchanging $a$ and $b$, we get also

(2)  $$|a-b|\geq |b|-|a|$$

Combining (1) and (2) we get our desired result.