# Prove $|a−b| \ge |a|−|b|$

Tags: real-analysis

I can't go anywhere with this. Thanks.
Prove that $|a - b| \ge |a| - |b|$. Hint: apply the triangle inequality to $|a| = |(a - b) + b|$.
Using the triangle inequality:
$$ |a + b| \le |a| + |b| \Rightarrow $$
$$ |a + b| \le |(a - b) + b| + |b| $$

Comment: Read the hint carefully. Perhaps it would help to rewrite the triangle inequality with different letters.

Comment: Yes. You must show your attempts, *even if* they failed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Triangle inequality for subtraction?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/214067/triangle-inequality-for-subtraction) - found using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Clvert%20a-b%5Crvert%5Cge%5Clvert%20a%5Crvert%20-%5Clvert%20b%5Crvert%24%2C%20OR%20content%3Atriangle%20inequality&p=1). Note this [answer](/a/214074) there shows how to use your provided hint. There's also other "reverse triangle" questions, e.g., [Similar to triangle (and reverse triangle) inequality, proof that $||x|-|y|| ≤ |x+y|$](/q/3236976).

Answer (score 0):

Prove that $|a - b| \ge |a| - |b|$
$$|a| = |(a - b) + b|$$
Apply the triangle inequality $|a + b| \le |a| + |b|$ by substituting $(a - b)$ for $|a|$:
$$|a| = |(a - b) + b| \le |a - b| + |b| \Rightarrow$$
$$|a| - |b| \le |a - b| \Rightarrow$$
$$|a - b| \ge |a| - |b|$$