# Prove that $|a - b| \geq |a| - |b|$

Tags: calculus

I'm not very sure how to proceed on this question. I tried breaking the $|a-b|$ into a piecewise function and showing that each of the functions of $|a-b|$ are greater than the right side but I cant figure it out. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Would you find it easier to prove $|a - b| + |b| \ge |a|$? (does this remind you of any identities/inequalities you know?)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: To @fiends, please ignore the comment from the Bot, your post is fine.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Triangle inequality for subtraction?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/214067/triangle-inequality-for-subtraction) - found using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Clvert%20a%20-%20b%5Crvert%5Cgeq%5Clvert%20a%5Crvert-%5Clvert%20b%5Crvert%24&p=1). Note this is closed as a duplicate of another question, and there are other duplicate questions linked to it, e.g., [Prove $|a−b| \ge |a|−|b|$](/q/4648703).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the triangle inequality

$$|x+y|\le |x|+|y|\tag1$$

then you can simply let $x=a-b$ and $y=b$.  Then from $(1)$ we see that

$$|a-b+b|=|a|\le |a-b|+|b|\tag2$$

Rearranging $(2)$ yields

$$|a-b|\ge |a|-|b|$$

and we are done!