# Completeness of $\langle \mathscr{C} [0, 1], \| \cdot \|_1 \rangle$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, banach-spaces

That's really embarrassing, however I need to ask it. I could not prove that the normed space    $\langle \mathscr{C} [0, 1], \| \cdot \|_1 \rangle $ is complete (as a metric space), where $\| f\|_1 = \int_0^1 |f(x)|dx$. I don't really know how to explicit a continuous functions as a limit of a Cauchy sequence. I tried to prove that the pointwise limit (of the Cauchy sequence) have just a finite number of discontinuities (I don't know if it's true) and then approximate it by a continuous function.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is not complete.  Perhaps you can come up with a sequence of continuous functions that converges (in $L_1$-norm) to  the characteristic funnction of $[0,1/2]$.  And then show why that answers your question.

Comment: @GEdgar This question appeared in some lecture notes of one professor of mine. But your counter example seems plausible.

Comment: I just did this today while studying for my prelim. Here's a nice sequence of functions in $C([0,1])$: $f_n(x)=\begin{cases}0&0\leq x\leq(1-n)/n\\ nx & (1-n)/2\leq x\leq (1+n)/2\\ 1 &  (1+n)/2\leq x\leq 1\end{cases}$. It's easy to show that $(f_n)$ is Cauchy with respect to $\|\cdot\|_1$, and hence this space is not complete. It's more tedious to show that it's *not* Cauchy with respect to $\|\cdot\|_{L^2}$, to verify that it's not a counterexample to $C([0,1])$ being complete with respect to $\|\cdot\|_{L^2}$.

Comment: @gmoss Thanks for the example.

Comment: The completion of $(C(X),\|\cdot\|_1)$ is the $L_1(X)$ space (by definition). On the other hand, as I can recall, it *is* complete w.r.t. the $\max$ norm.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This space is not complete. Consider functions
$$
f_n(t)=\begin{cases}0\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad t\in\left(0,\frac{1}{2} -\frac{1}{2n}\right)\\\frac{1}{2}+n\left(t-\frac{1}{2}\right)\qquad t\in\left[\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2n},\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2n}\right]\\1\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad t\in\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2n},1\right)\end{cases}
$$
It is easy to check that $\{f_n\}_{n=1}^\infty\subset \mathscr{C}([0,1])$. Moreover this is a Cauchy sequence. Indeed
$$
\lim\limits_{N\to\infty}\sup\limits_{m,n>N}\Vert f_n-f_m\Vert_1
=\lim\limits_{N\to\infty}\sup\limits_{m,n>N}2^{-2}|n^{-1}-m^{-1}|
\leq\lim\limits_{N\to\infty}2^{-1}N^{-1}=0
$$
Assume that there exist $f\in \mathscr{C}([0,1])$ such that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\Vert f_n-f\Vert_1=0$.

Assume that there exist $t_0\in\left(\frac{1}{2},1\right)$ such that $f(t_0)\neq 1$. Since $f$ is continuous then there exists a neighborhood $U_\delta(t_0)$ such that $|f(t)-f(t_0)|\leq\frac{|1-f(t_0)|}{2}$ for all $t\in U_\delta(t_0)$. In particular, by [reverse triangle inequality](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/127372/prove-that-x-y-le-x-y) we have
$$
\begin{align}
|1-f(t)|
&=|(1-f(t_0))-(f(t)-f(t_0))|\\
&\geq\left||1-f(t_0)|-|f(t)-f(t_0)|\right|\\
&\geq\frac{|1-f(t_0)|}{2}.
\end{align}
$$
Now take $\delta'=\min\left(\delta,1-t_0,t_0-\frac{1}{2}\right)$, so we can assume $U_{\delta'}(t_0)\subset \left(\frac{1}{2},1\right)\cap U_\delta(t_0)$. Pick any natural number $N>\frac{1}{2(t_0-\delta')-1}$, then for all $n>N$ we have $U_{\delta'}(t_0)\subset \left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2n},1\right)$. Note that for all $n>N$ and $t\in U_{\delta'}(t_0)$ we have $f_n(t)=1$, so
$$
\Vert f_n-f\Vert_1=
\int\limits_{(0,1)}|f_n(t)-f(t)|dt\geq
\int\limits_{(t_0-\delta',t_0+\delta')}|f_n(t)-f(t)|dt=
$$
$$
\int\limits_{(t_0-\delta',t_0+\delta')}|1-f(t)|dt\geq
\int\limits_{(t_0-\delta',t_0+\delta')}\frac{|1-f(t_0)|}{2}dt
=\delta'|1-f(t_0)|>0
$$
and as the consequence
$$
0=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\Vert f_n-f\Vert_1\geq\delta'|1-f(t_0)|>0
$$
Contradiction, therefore $f(t_0)=1$ for all $t_0\in\left(\frac{1}{2},1\right)$. Similarly one can show that for all $t_0\in\left(0,\frac{1}{2}\right)$ we also have $f(t_0)=0$. Now note that
$$
\lim\limits_{t\to 1/2-0}f(t)=0\qquad\qquad\lim\limits_{t\to 1/2+0}f(t)=1
$$
so $f$ is not continuous. Contradiction, hence $\mathscr{C}([0,1])$ is not complete.

Comment: Good complete answer to the problem.  This same question has been asked many times, but this answer seems to be the only one that handles the subtlety to show that if the sequence has a limit, that limit has to be equal to the pointwise limit in this case (which is not continuous, hence the contradiction).  IMO this question should kept and the linked question is the one that should be closed as duplicate instead.

Comment: I think there is a typo. Is $f$ identically zero on $(0,\frac{1}{2})$ instead?

Comment: @Steve, indeed. Thank you.

Comment: @Norbert Nice anwser, I am trying to understand the mysterious calculations you've done, so I opened a question about that. Just letting you know in case you want to answer it, since you would be the most appropriate person.  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4360066/how-do-i-make-sense-of-the-anwser-given-in-this-post-to-prove-the-non-completen

Comment: @J.C.VegaO, thank you for proofreading my sloppy written post. There was no need to write your questions as a separate post. We can discuss it here in the comments. I've fixed all typos and mistakes that you've pointed out. Feel free to ask questions regarding the latest edit of my post.

Comment: Thank you,I think in the last integrant you're missing the absolute value, since you're using $|1-f(t)|\geq\frac{|1-f(t_0)|}{2}$ I guess

Comment: $\int\limits_{(t_0-\delta',t_0+\delta')}\frac{1-f(t_0)}{2}dt\geq \delta'(1-f(t_0))$ I thing this should be an equality

Comment: If the objective is to have $U_{\delta'}(t_0)=(t_0-\delta',t_0+\delta')\subset \left(\frac{1}{2},1\right)$, then I would impose $t_0-\delta'>\frac{1}{2}$ and $t_0+\delta'<1$ . That is $\delta'<t_0-\frac{1}{2}$ and $\delta'<1-t_0 $, so I would take $\delta'=\min\left(1-t_0,t_0-\frac{1}{2}\right)$ . So why $\delta'=\min\left(\delta,t_0-\frac{1}{2}\right)$? Shouldn't it be $\delta'=\min\left(1-t_0,t_0-\frac{1}{2}\right)$ or $\delta'=\min\left(\delta,1-t_0,t_0-\frac{1}{2}\right)$ (not sure how to put the $\delta$ inside)

Comment: I am not sure how you get $ \left||1-f(t_0)|-|f(t)-f(t_0)|\right| =\frac{|1-f(t_0)|}{2}$ in the third line of the reverse triangle inequality

Comment: I am not sure why you use $ \lim\limits_{N\to\infty}\sup\limits_{m,n>N}$ to prove $f_n$ is Cauchy. I have only seen people take the limit for $n,m \to 0$ of$  ||f_n -f_m||_1$

Comment: @J.C.VegaO I want to ensure that $U_{\delta'}(t_0)\subset \left(\frac{1}{2},1\right)\cap U_\delta(t_0)$, hence the choice of $\delta'$ as $\min\left(\delta,1-t_0,t_0-\frac{1}{2}\right)$.

Comment: @J.C.VegaO fixed the third line of the reverse triangle inequality

Comment: @J.C.VegaO I use $\lim_{N\to\infty}\sup_{n,m>N}$ because this is a more rigorous way to take the limit as $m$ and $n$ tend to infinity

Comment: Yes, but in the reverse triangle inequality, how do you do this $\left||1-f(t_0)|-|f(t)-f(t_0)|\right| \geq\frac{|1-f(t_0)|}{2}.$

Comment: Note that $|f(t)-f(t_0)|\leq \frac{|1-f(t_0)|}{2}$, so $-|f(t)-f(t_0)|\geq -\frac{|1-f(t_0)|}{2}$, hence $|1-f(t_0)|-|f(t)-f(t_0)|\geq |1-f(t_0)|-\frac{|1-f(t_0)|}{2}=\frac{|1-f(t_0)|}{2}$. Finally $||1-f(t_0)|-|f(t)-f(t_0)||=|\frac{|1-f(t_0)|}{2}|$. This is so trivial!