# $C([0, 1])$ is not complete with respect to the norm $\lVert f\rVert _1 = \int_0^1 \lvert f (x) \rvert \,dx$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Consider $C([0, 1])$, the linear space of continuous complex-valued functions
on the interval $[0, 1]$, with the norm

$$\displaystyle\lVert f\rVert_1 = \int_0^1 \lvert f(x)\rvert \,dx.$$

I have to show that $C([0, 1])$ is not complete with respect to this norm. I have found the following example from a book.

Let $f_n \in C[0,1]$ be given by

$$f_n(x) := \begin{cases}
 0   & \text{if $0 \le x \le \frac1{2}$}\\
 n(x-\frac{1}{2}) & \text{if $\frac {1}{2} < x \le \frac {1}{2} + \frac {1}{n}$}\\
 1              & \text{if $ \frac {1}{2} + \frac {1}{n} <x \leq 1 $}
\end{cases}$$

How to prove that $f_n$  is a Cauchy sequence with respect to $\lVert \cdot\rVert_1$?

If I use basic definition then I have to prove that $\lVert f_n - f_m\rVert_1 < \epsilon$ $\forall n, m > N$. But I am finding it difficult to prove this.

Please help me to understand how to prove that $f_n$ is Cauchy sequence in $C([0, 1])$.

Thanks

Comment: "I am confused with whether I have to choose $f_n = 0$, $1$ or $n(x-\tfrac12)$." I don't understand this. Each $f_n$ is a continuous function on the unit interval given by the formula provided. Nowhere is there a choice involved.

Comment: The proof goes as almost all proofs in basic real analysis: "Let $\epsilon > 0$ be given. We are to find a natural number $N$ (depending on $\epsilon$) such that when $m,n \geq N$, then [$\ldots$]" - The only challenge lies in picking $N$ large enough. I suggest drawing a picture so you can see how to pick a good $N$.

Comment: Please take a look at my edit to see the corrections I made to your TeX. Particularly note `\lvert\lvert -> \lVert`.

Comment: See also: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/814305/let-v-c0-1-cdot-with-f-int-01fx-dx-consider-the and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1479443/c0-1-with-l1-norm-is-not-banach-space

Comment: But how to prove that $f_n$ is not convergent with respect to this norm ?

Comment: @mathscrazy I know its been years since, but I am wondering what book did you find this example at?

Comment: @Ugo I just forgot from which book I got this problem but will search it for you. Thanks

Comment: The other answers here are incomplete. For a complete answer, see https://math.stackexchange.com/a/375234/52912

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let $m\leq n$ both natural numbers, then
$$\|f_n-f_m\|_1 = \int_0^1 |f_n(x)-f_m(x)|\,\mathrm{d}x $$
$$ = \int_\frac{1}{2}^{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{n}}(n-m)\left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)\,\mathrm{d}x + \int_{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{n}}^{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{m}}\left(1-m\left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)\right)\,\mathrm{d}x.$$

Now try to bound these integrals for $n,m\geq N$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Why we need to break the inteval from ${\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{n}}$ to ${\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{m}}$? Do I have ot integrate this integral and then only bound of this integral can be found.

Comment: Because between $\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{n}$ and $\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{m}$, $f_n(x) = 1$, whereas $f_m(x) = m(x-\frac{1}{2})$. Both integrals are easy to compute, so you could just do that. I believe you'll end up with $\frac{1}{2m}-\frac{1}{2n}$, which is quite easy to bound.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I understood fully now. Later on It could be bounded by $\frac{1}{2m}< \frac{1}{N} < \epsilon $.

Answer (score 6):

Its correct but some part is still left. You have to show that it is not complete.
For this we need to show that limit point is not continuous. Suppose function f(x) is the limit. Observe that it is not right continuous at x=1/2. hence it is not complete