# Let $V:= (C([0,1]),\|\cdot\|$) with $\|f\|:= \int_0^1|f(x)| \ dx$. Consider the function $f_n$ and show that V is not a Banach Space.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, banach-spaces, cauchy-sequences

The Assignment:

> Let $V:= (C([0,1]),\|\cdot\|$) with $\|f\|:= \int_0^1|f(x)| \ dx$. Consider the continuous function $f$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$:
>
> $$f_n: [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R},  \ x\rightarrow \begin{cases}
> 1  & \text{, $\ $0 ≤ x ≤ $\frac{1}{2}$}\\[2ex]
> 1- (n+1)(x-\frac{1}{2}) & \text{, $\frac{1}{2} < x ≤ \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{n+1}$}  \\[2ex]
> 0 & \text{, $\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{n+1} < x ≤ 1$}
> \end{cases} $$
>
> Show with $f_n$ that $V$ is not a Banach space.

I want to show that $f_n$ is Cauchy but also that the limit function $f$ is not continuous and hence $ \notin C([0,1])$. The second part is obvious, since $f$ is not continous at $\frac{1}{2}$.

What I tried is that: Let $n≥m$:
\begin{align}  \|f_n - f_m\| &= \int_0^1 | f_n(x) - f_m(x) | \ dx \\
&= \int_\frac{1}{2}^{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{n+1}} | f_n(x) - f_m(x) | \ dx + \int_{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{n+1}}^{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{m+1}} | f_n(x) - f_m(x) | \ dx\\
&= \int_\frac{1}{2}^{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{n+1}} | (m-n) |\left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right) \ dx + \int_{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{n+1}}^{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{m+1}} 0 - (1 - (m+1)\left(x-\frac{1}{2})\right) \ dx \\
&= ( n-m)\left[\frac{1}{2}x^2 - \frac{1}{2}\right]_\frac{1}{2}^{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{n+1}} + (...) = (...)
\end{align}

Are my calculations and my idea correct so far? Since the calculating by hand gets messy with the int-intervals (at least in my opinion), I used maple to get:

$$(...) = -\frac{1}{2} \frac{(m-n)(3m+2-n)}{(m+1)(n+1)^2}$$

Which doesn't seem right, which is why I was wondering if I made a typo or I did a mistake before.

I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: Well. I think it will be easier to consider $||f_n - f_m|| \leq ||f_n - f|| + ||f_m - f||$ (note that $||f_n - f||$ still makes sense.

Comment: ... Good idea. - However, I'm still having problems determining the $N$ such that for larger $n≥m$ the inequality holds. The approach yields:
$\|f_n - f_m\| ≤ \int_\frac{1}{2}^{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{n+1}} 1 - (n+1)(x-\frac{1}{2}) dx + \int_\frac{1}{2}^{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{m+1}} 1 - (m+1)(x-\frac{1}{2}) dx = \frac{1}{2} \frac{m+n+2}{(n+1)(m+1)} <  \frac{m+n+2}{(n+1)(m+1)}$. How do I go further from here?

Comment: You dont have to be so precise here. You can approximate $\int_{\frac 12}^{\frac 12 + \frac{1}{n+1}}1- (n+1) (x-\frac 12) dx \leq \frac{1}{n+1}$ and similarly for the second term, so $||f_n - f_m|| \leq  \frac{1}{n+1} + \frac{1}{m+1}$.

Comment: I'm not seeing it, why can you approximate the integral like that?

Comment: I just forget about the term $(n+1)(x-\frac 12)$ as it is positive on $[\frac 12, \frac 12 + \frac{1}{n+1}]$

Comment: Thanks a lot, John! Too bad, I cannot close this thread with your answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [$C[0,1]$ with $L^1$ norm is not Banach space.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1479443/c0-1-with-l1-norm-is-not-banach-space)

Comment: See also: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/402841/c0-1-is-not-complete-space-with-respect-to-norm-lvert-f-rvert-1-int