# An explicit non-converging Cauchy sequence in $C[0,1]$ with $L^{1/2}$ metric

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functional-analysis, cauchy-sequences

I am trying to construct a sequence of functions in $C[0,1]$ with the $L^{1/2}$ metric
$$d(f, g) = \int_0^1 \sqrt{|f(x) - g(x)|} \,dx$$
that is Cauchy but not convergent.

There are a [whole](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/336417/completeness-of-langle-mathscrc-0-1-cdot-1-rangle/375234#375234) [bunch](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1479443/c0-1-with-l1-norm-is-not-banach-space) [of](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/402841/c0-1-is-not-complete-with-respect-to-the-norm-lvert-f-rvert-1-int-0) [questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/814305/let-v-c0-1-cdot-with-f-int-01fx-dx-consider-the) on the site with examples for $L^1$ (though they're all basically the same), and I've been trying to adapt them for this case. Unfortunately, no matter how I tweak my sequence it makes calculating the actual distance $d(f_n,f_m)$ (and showing that this goes to $0$, etc.) very difficult, because of the square root.

Does anyone have a concrete and reasonably computable example to show that $C[0,1]$ is not complete with the $L^{1/2}$ metric? Your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $n=1,2,\dots,$  define $f_n(x)= 1/x, 1/n\le x \le 1,$ $f_n(x)= n, 0\le x \le 1/n.$ This is a sequence in $C[0,1]$ that converges to $1/x$ in $L^{1/2}.$

Comment: But $d(f_n,f_m)$ still requires me to integrate $\sqrt{1/x -  m}$, which I can't do...

Comment: You don't need to do that. $f_n$ converges in $L^{1/2}$ to $1/x,$ therefore $f_n$ is Cauchy in $L^{1/2}.$

Comment: But to show that it converges to $1/x$, don't I need to show that $\int_0^1 \sqrt{1/x - f_n(x)} \,dx = \int_0^{1/n} \sqrt{1/x - n} \,dx$ goes to $0$?

Comment: Yes you do. That integral is less than

$$\int_0^{1/n} x^{-1/2}\, dx = 2x^{1/2}\big |_0^{1/n} =2/\sqrt n \to 0.$$