# The function is not continuous

Tags: vector-spaces, continuity, normed-spaces

$$C([a,b])=\{ f: [a,b] \to \mathbb{R} \text{ continuous} \}$$

$C([a,b])$ is a linear space.

For $f \in C([a,b])$ we define $\|f\|_{\infty}:= \sup_{x \in [a,b]} |f(x)|$ and easily it can be shown that the space $(C([a,b]),\| \cdot\|_\infty)$ is a space with norm.

For $f \in C([a,b])$ we define $\|f\|:= \int_a^b |f(x)| \, dx$

and it can be easily shown that the space $(C([a,b]), \|\cdot\|)$ is a space with norm.

$$(f,g) \mapsto \|f-g\|=\int_a^b |f(x)-g(x)|\,dx$$

[image]

There is a $f_n \in C([a,b])$ such that $\|f_n-g\| \to 0$ but $g \notin C([a,b])$.

Could you give me an example of such a function?

Also does the last proposition also hold if we consider $\|f\|_\infty:= \sup_{x \in [a,b]} |f(x)|$ ?

Comment: What is $g$? Perhaps [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/402841/c0-1-is-not-complete-space-with-respect-to-norm-lvert-f-rvert-1-int) is what you're after.

Comment: When you write $\|f\|$ instead of $||f||$ then you see a $\|f\|\|g\|$ instead of $||f||||g||$, and you see the difference in spacing.  The former notation is standard and I changed it in the question. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Consider the set of functions

$$f_n(x) = \begin{cases} 0, & x \in \left[0, \frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2n}\right) \\ nx + \frac{1-n}{2}, & x \in \left[\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2n},\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2n}\right] \\ 1, & x\in\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2n},1\right]\end{cases}$$

Does this seemingly converge to anything in the $L^1$ norm? If so, is that function continuous? This can easily be adapted to $C([a,b])$ in general.

Comment: How can we find where it converges?

Comment: Where it converges isn't important for this problem. Try plotting it for various values of $n$ to get an idea.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever $f_n\rightarrow g$ you can change a value of $g$ such that $g$ is not continuous. But changing a value of $g$ does not change $\int_a^b |f_n(x)-g(x)|dx$ so you still have $f_n\rightarrow g$...

Comment: Could you explain it further to me?