# $C[0,1]$ is not complete under $L^1$ norm proof verification and request

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, continuity, metric-spaces

I need to show that $C[0,1]$ is not complete under the norm $||f|| = \int^{1}_{0}|f|$(usual Riemann Integral). For this I had the idea that I need to somehow make the limit discontinuous at atleast a point to get a contradiction. I considered the following candidate:

\begin{align*}
f_n(x) = -nx+1,  x\leq 1/n\\
=0, x>1/n
\end{align*}
Then we have($n>m$):
\begin{align*}
||f_n-f_m|| = \int^1_{0} |f_n-f_m| = \int^{1/m}_{0}|f_n-f_m| \leq \frac{1}{m}
\end{align*}
Hence given $\epsilon>0$, we can find an $N$ so that $||f_n-f_m||<\epsilon, \forall n>m>N$. But if we take the limit:
\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} f_n(x) &= 0, x>0\\
&= 1, x=0 
\end{align*}
which is clearly discontinuous.

Q1: Is the following example sufficient to conclude that the space is incomplete?

Q2: How bad can we make the example? Is it possible to get a limit function so discontinuous that the limit is not integrable in any neighbourhood?

Comment: This is not the right approach. In fact, this sequence converges in the $L^1$ norm to the zero function!

Comment: @diracdeltafunk Could you please elaborate, I thought that the limit function should be inside the vector space ...?

Comment: "Convergence in $L_1$" is a different criterion from "Pointwise convergence". So you should not expect the results to be the same. You have found the pointwise limit, and claim it is the only $L_1$ limit.

Comment: @Rohan First, a question that might help you think this through: what does "complete under the $L^1$ norm" mean?

Comment: Oh ok, I understand, if $f_n$ converges with respect to $L_1$ to $f$ then $||f_n-f||\rightarrow 0$ as n\rightarrow \infty$, may not converge pointwise

Comment: That make sense, so in fact this sequence is convergent in $L_1$ to $0$...thanks a lot

Comment: Right! Still, you can try to make something like this work. The main problem with your sequence is that the pointwise limit is "almost continuous" -- it only needs to be modified at a single point to become continuous, and this doesn't change its integral. Instead, try to find a sequence whose pointwise limit is a relatively simple function, but discontinuous in a more serious way!

Comment: The completion is $L^{1}[0,1]$ and this tells us how bad the limit can be.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4564347/ and its linked posts

Comment: If you modify your example by shifting the discontinuity in the limit to the middle of the interval:
$$
f(x)=\cases{1&for $\ 0\le x\le \frac{1}{2}$\\
1+n\left(\frac{1}{2}-x\right)&for $\ \frac{1}{2}<x<\frac{n+2}{2n}$\\
0&for $\ \frac{n+2}{2n}\le x\le1$}
$$
that should give you a sequence which does what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Thank you very much for your responses!

Comment: @Ionza Is the logic the following: Suppose there exists a limit function in $C[0,1]$. Then if it is continuous at every $x \geq 1/2$, and is nonzero, there must be a small neighbourhood where it is nonzero; then we can estimate $||f_n-f||$ and claim it cannot be arbitrarily small. Hence it must be $0$ for $x\geq 1/2$. On the other hand we can show that it must be $1$ in the left half by the same logic, and thus we cannot get a continuous limit with respect to $L^1$?

Comment: @Rohan Didmishe The argument is simpler than that.  First I note that there's a typo in my previous comment—$\ f(x)\ $ should have been $\ f_n(x)\ $.  With $\ f_n(x)\ $ thus defined and
$$
f(x)=\cases{1&for $\ 0\le x\le\frac{1}{2}$\\
            0&for $\ \frac{1}{2}<x\le1$}
$$
you should be able to show that $\ \lim_\limits{n\rightarrow\infty}f_n=f\ $ with respect to the $\ L^1\ $ norm.

Comment: Since $\ f_n\in C[0,1]\ $ for all $\ n\ $ but $\ f\not\in C[0,1]\ $ this means that $\ f\in$$\,\text{cl}_{L^1}(C[0,1])\setminus C[0,1]\ $, so $\ C[0,1]\ $ is not closed and hence not complete with respect to the $\ L^1\ $ norm.