# Incompleteness of $(C[a,b], \| \cdot \|_1)$

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis, analysis, banach-spaces, normed-spaces

Consider $C([a,b])$, the vector space of continuous functions in $[a,b] \subset \mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$. Let be $f \in C([a,b])$, we define $\|\cdot\|_1$ as follows:
\begin{equation*} 
\|f\|_1 =  \int_{a}^{b}|f(x)|dx 
\end{equation*}

I must show that $(C([a,b]), \|\cdot\|_1)$ is *not* a Banach space.

This is my answer the which one is wrong according to my teacher. Consider the following counterexample. Let $c =2^{-1}(a+b)$ y $f_n:[a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R} \hspace{.1cm} \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$ with the following association rule and graph:
[image]

It's clear that $\{f_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \subset C([a,b])$. We will show that $\{f_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ it's a $||\cdot||_1-Cauchy$ sequence. Let be $\epsilon > 0$ and $N = \displaystyle \left\lceil{ \frac{1}{2 \epsilon}}\right\rceil$, then:
\begin{equation*}
    ||f_n-f_m||_1 = \int_{a}^{b} |f_n(x)-f_m(x)|dx = \left| \frac{1}{2n}-\frac{1}{2m} \right| \leq \max \left\{ \frac{1}{2n}, \frac{1}{2m}\right\} < \epsilon, \hspace{.1cm} \forall n,m \geq N
\end{equation*}
So the sequence is $||\cdot||_1-Cauchy$,
however though this sequence converges to the following limit function, the limit function is clearly discontinuous. Let be $f:[a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$:
\begin{equation*} f(x) = 
    \begin{cases}
        1 & \text{si $x \leq c$}\\
        0 & \text{si $x > c$}
    \end{cases}
\end{equation*}
Fixed $\epsilon_1 > 0$ and $N_1 = \left\lceil{\displaystyle\frac{1}{2 \epsilon_1}}\right\rceil$, then:
\begin{equation*}
||f_n-f||_1 = \displaystyle\int_{0}^{1} |f_n(x)-f(x)| = \frac{1}{2n} < \epsilon, \hspace{.1cm} \forall n \geq N_1
\end{equation*}
$\textbf{Now, the problem is that}$ (according to my teacher) I only have propose a discontinuous function wich is a limit of the sequence, this does not means that do not exits another continuous function wich is also the limit of the sequence. I understand the problem, but nothing comes up to me to solve this.

Comment: Check this: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/336417/42969.

Comment: Can you show the pointwise limit of a sequence in your Banach space is unique *if* it exists? That would do it, and to me it looks true by considering the real sequences formed by evaluating each term of the sequence at a fixed point. [I may be wrong about this, not being an expert...]

Comment: Hint: Suppose that $f_n$ did converge to a continuous function $f$. Then, since $f$ is continuous, there exists $\delta$ such that if $|x-c|<\delta$, then $|f(x)-f(c)|<1/2$.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $f_n \to f \in C[0,1]$ with the $\|\cdot \|_1$ norm.

Let $g$ be $1$ on $[a,c]$ and $0$ on $(c,b]$. It is clear that $f_n \to g$ uniformly on $K_\epsilon = [a,b] \setminus (c-\epsilon, c+\epsilon)$ and that $g$ is continuous on $\{c\}^c$.

Let $\|\cdot \|_{K_\epsilon}$ be the $1$-norm on $K_\epsilon$, then
$\|f-g\|_{K_\epsilon} \le \|f-f_n\|_{K_\epsilon} + \|f_n -g\|_{K_\epsilon} \le \|f-f_n\|_1 + \|f_n -g\|_{K_\epsilon}$ from which we see that $f=g$ on $K_\epsilon$ (since both $f,g$ are continuous).

In particular, we must have $f=g$ on $\{c\}^c$ and so $f$ is discontinuous, which is a contradiction.