# How to prove $\lvert \lVert x \rVert - \lVert y \rVert \rvert \overset{\heartsuit}{\leq} \lVert x-y \rVert$?

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, vector-spaces, normed-spaces

I'm trying to show that $\lvert \lVert x \rVert - \lVert y \rVert \rvert \overset{\heartsuit}{\leq} \lVert x-y \rVert$. A hint would be nice.

Comment: What is that heart stands for? I am not able to understand.

Comment: Wikipedia: [Reverse triangle inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_triangle_inequality); ProofWiki: [Reverse Triangle Inequality](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Reverse_Triangle_Inequality).

Comment: @srijan: I think the elements in LHS is so eager to be less that the RHS ones. Wholeheartedly eager!.

Comment: Maybe this calls for the love triangle inequality.

Comment: The same thing for absolute value was asked here: [Reverse Triangle Inequality Proof](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/127372/reverse-triangle-inequality-proof). It is a special case of your question, but the proofs are very similar.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Observe that

$\lVert x \rVert  = \lVert (x -y) +y \rVert \leq \lVert (x -y) \rVert + \lVert y \rVert$

which gives

$\lVert x \rVert - \lVert y \rVert \leq \lVert x -y \rVert$ ... $(1)$

Further,

$-(\lVert x \rVert - \lVert y \rVert ) \leq \lVert (y -x) \rVert = \lVert (x -y) \rVert $... $(2)$

From $(1)$ and $(2)$ result follows.

Comment: thank's it helped me a lot

Answer (score 8):

Use triangle inequality and norm properties to show that $$\lVert x\rVert-\lVert y\rVert\le\lVert x-y\rVert$$ and $$\lVert y\rVert-\lVert x\rVert\le\lVert x-y\rVert$$

Answer (score 5):

How about applying the triangle inequality to $\parallel x - y + y \parallel$?

Comment: Fastest way to get the proof done

Comment: @Gabriel: Half-done, anyway.

Comment: @CameronBuie in cases like these where I am not sure if something is homework, I'd rather give an idea than a solution. Well, a full solution anyway.

Comment: $\frac{\text{self improvement}}{\text{homework}}$