# Limit of absolute value of sequence

Tags: calculus, limits

Prove that if $\lim \{a_n\}\to a$ then $\lim \{|a_n|\}\to|a|$. Is the converse true?

I don't know where to start. Should I break this into 2 cases?

Comment: you can go back to the definition of limit, with $\epsilon$.

Comment: What do you think about $a_n=(-1)^n$

Comment: What do you mean? The limits as $n \to \infty$?

Comment: In addition to dkuper's comment, you are probably missing a property of $|.|$ : $||a|-|b||\leq |a-b|$

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- By definition, if $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_n=a$$ then for all $\varepsilon>0$ there exists a $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n \geq N$ implies $|a_n-a| \leq \varepsilon$.
- We may also verify case-by-case that $$\big||x|-|y|\big| \leq |x-y|$$ for all $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$.  In particular,$$\big||a_n|-|a|\big| \leq |a_n-a|.$$

Combining these yields the proof.

Comment: Maybe it is worth mentioning that this inequality is called [reverse triangle inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_triangle_inequality) and some proofs can be found also [here on MSE](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/127372/reverse-triangle-inequality-proof).