# Prove that $|x - y| \geq |x| - |y|$

Tags: inequality

For some reason I come to an answer that contradicts that, so I'm wrong.

$-|x| \leq x \leq |x|$ and $-|y| \leq y \leq |y|$

so subtract $x$ from $y$: $-(|x| - |y|) \leq x - y \leq |x| - |y|$

so by the Triangle Inequality: $|x - y| \leq |x| - |y|$

Somewhere I'm going in the wrong direction.

Tell me what's going on there.

P.S. How do I use the proper \leq symbol?

Comment: <= in $LaTex$ can be written as \le or \leq

Comment: Here, you find a very good answer and explanation: [Reverse Triangle Inequality](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/127372/reverse-triangle-inequality-proof)

Comment: @Joe If you want, LaTeX can be written `$\LaTeX$` or $\LaTeX$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$|x|=|x-y+y|\le|x-y|+|y|\implies |x|-|y|\le |x-y|$$

Comment: Great, makes sense. Thanks DonAntonio!

Answer (score 1):

The step where you subtract is wrong. If you have two inequalities
$$a \leq a'$$
and
$$b \leq b',$$
then if you want to subtract you should make sure to write
$$ a - b' \leq a' - b$$
instead of $a-b \leq a'-b'$.
(Can you see why? Think about it in full sentences. Subtracting a big number leaves a smaller result than subtracting a small number.)

Comment: As a general strategy for finding where your mistake is, plug in some easy numbers.

Comment: I just realised that now. So I'm convinced that's the case. I've played around with that for a while now. It hasn't taken me in the direction needed. Could you perhaps give me more information?

Answer (score 0):

Your second step is incorrect.  As a counterexample, try $x = -2, y = 3$.  Then 
$$
-(|x|-|y|) = -(2 - 3) = -(-1) = 1 
$$
which is definitely greater than 
$$
x-y = -2 -3 = -5
$$