# Check proof of some simple inequality

Tags: inequality, proof-verification, proof-writing

Can you check please my proof of this inequality? It's all right?

[image]

Comment: See an easier proof of (a) at this question [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/127372/reverse-triangle-inequality-proof)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's all right, but in point **b)** you have mistake: need $\ge$, not $\le$.

Comment: Oh, yes... Right. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Most of your proof is right, while some errors occur in part b).
First, you need to prove that $|x+x_1+\cdots+x_n|\color{red}\ge|x|-(|x_1|+\cdots+|x_n|)$.
Also, it should be $|x|\le|\color{red}x+x_1+\cdots+x_n|+|-x_1|+\cdots+|-x_n|$.