# Prove that |a -b| $\geq$ ||a| - |b|| $\forall$ a,b $\in$ $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, proof-verification, triangles, absolute-value

Here is my proof can anyone check if it needs more detail or if it's good?

Since a = a - b + b, then by the triangle inequality, |a| $\geq$ ||a| - |b|| + |b| so that |a| - |b| $\geq$ ||a| - |b|| since ||a| - |b|| = |a| - |b|
$\therefore$ |a - b| $\geq$ ||a| - |b||

Comment: Does not look good. You say "the triangle inequality", but what you apply is not it. Take $x=a-b$ and $y=b$, then you have $a=x+y$. How does the triangle inequality for $|x+y|$ look like?

Comment: It will look like this|x| + |y|

Comment: BTW you can find several posts about this inequality on this site. Like [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/127372/reverse-triangle-inequality-proof) and [other posts linked there](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/127372).

Answer (score 1):

Since both sides are non-negative, the inequality holds if and only if 
$$(a-b)^2\ge (|a|-|b|)^2,$$
that is, if and only if
$$a^2-2ab+b^2\ge a^2-2|ab|+b^2.$$
But this inequality is obvious.

Answer (score 0):

If $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$, then $a = tb$ for some $t \in \mathbb{R}$. Then $|a-b| = |b||t - 1|$ and $||a| - |b|| = |b|||t|-1|$. If $t \geq 0$ then $|a-b| = ||a| - |b||$; if $t < 0$ then $||t| - 1| = |-t-1|$, so $|a-b| > ||a| - |b||$.