# Prove $||a| - |b||$ is less than or equal to $|a-b|$

Tags: inequality, triangles, absolute-value

I was given the hint to split it into two cases ($|a| - |b|$ being positive and negative) and then use the triangle inequality. However, since the triangle inequality says that $|a+b|$ is less than or equal to $|a| + |b|$, so I don't see how I can use that to help since I'm dealing with subtraction. I've tried using the definition of absolute value, and I was able to find that $||a| - |b||$ = $|a| - |b|$ in my first case, but I couldn't do much with that.

Comment: You may change the subtraction $x-y$ into the addition $x+(-y)$ (this is the _definition_ of subtraction, after all), which should enable the triangle inequality.

Comment: See also [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/127372/reverse-triangle-inequality-proof) and other posts [linked there](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/127372).

Answer (score 3):

You may write
$$
x=x-y+y
$$ giving, by the [triangle inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality),
$$
|x|\leq |x-y|+|y|
$$ or

> $$
> |x|-|y|\leq|x-y|
> $$

then *do the same starting this time with* $$y=y-x+x.$$

Comment: Instead of your last step we can do this : after getting $|x|-|y| \le |x-y|$, we can just swap $x$ & $y$ in it to get $|y|-|x| \le |y-x|=|x-y|$

Comment: @VikrantDesai Right, but "swapping" $x$ and $y$ is fact doing the same thing as starting with $y$.

Comment: Yes I know that. :D

Answer (score 1):

You may prove $(|a|-|b|)^2 \leq (a-b)^2$, since $2|a||b| \geq 2ab$. By taking positive absolute values, you obtain $||a|-|b|| \leq |a-b|$.