# How to prove that $|a-b|<\epsilon$ implies $|b|-\epsilon<|a|<|b|+\epsilon$?

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, real-numbers

Given  $ a, b, \varepsilon  \in  \mathbb{R} $ prove that

$$|a-b|<\varepsilon \implies |b| - \varepsilon < |a| < |b|+\varepsilon. $$

Hi,  I need help for proof this expression, which could be used arguments or results. I would appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: [Hint](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/127372/reverse-triangle-inequality-proof): $||a|-|b||\leq|a-b|$.

Comment: Thank you and I understand .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want to show is $-\varepsilon<|a|-|b|<\varepsilon$, which is equivalent to $||a|-|b||<\varepsilon$. From triangle inequality you know that $|a|\leq |b|+|a-b|$, so $|a|-|b|\leq |a-b|$. Similarly $|b|-|a|\leq |a-b|$. This means $||a|-|b||\leq |a-b|<\varepsilon$, as you want.

Comment: Thank you and I understand .

Comment: No problem, glad to help!

Answer (score 1):

By reverse triangle inequality, we have $||a|-|b||\leq |a-b|<\varepsilon$.
Hence, $|a|-|b|<\varepsilon$ (i.e. $|a|<|b|+\varepsilon$) and $|b|-|a|<\varepsilon$ (i.e. $|b|-\varepsilon < |a|$).

Comment: Thank you and I understand .

Comment: You're welcome.