# $||a|-|b|| \leq |a-b|$ - vector equivalent

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, vectors, euclidean-geometry, absolute-value

Let $\left|\cdot\right|$ be absolute value of a real number. Let $\langle\cdot\rangle$ be two-dimensional, Euclidean vector's norm.

Let **a**$\, =(x_1,y_1)$ and let **b** $=(x_2,y_2)$ .

I have the result that $||r_1|-|r_2||\leq |r_1-r_2|$ for $r_1,r_2\in\mathbb R$.

How do I prove that $\big|\big<$**a**$\big>-\big<$**b**$\big>\big|\leq\big<$**a**-**b**$\big>$?

Comment: This is the reverse triangle inequality ... a proof is given here 
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/127372/reverse-triangle-inequality-proof

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I note the euclidean norm $\|\cdot \|$, and the scalar product $\langle \cdot , \cdot\rangle$
$$
\|a-b\|^2 = \langle a-b, a-b \rangle = \|a\|^2 + \|b\|^2 - 2\langle a, b \rangle.
$$
Or, using the Cauchy-Schwartz inequality 
$$
\langle a, b \rangle \le | \langle a, b \rangle | \le \| a\| \|b\|
$$
So 
$$
\|a-b\|^2 \ge (\|a\| - \|b\|)^2
$$
And hence
$$
\|a - b\|  \ge | \|a\| - \|b\| |.
$$

Comment: Just a formatting hint: Using \| instead of || makes nicer norm bars (closer together). This becomes important when mixing with absolut value signs. Compare $|\|a\|-\|b\||$ with $|||a||-||b|||$. Apart from that: you probably have mistyped your last inequality.

Comment: Thanks, didn't know that, edited !

Comment: Much easier to read this way. ;-)

Comment: You have a typo in your last equation. Change the left side accordingly.

Comment: Yes, thank you, mistake changing the $|$.