# How do I show that $ ||x| - |y||\leq|x - y| $

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality

How do I show that $$ ||x| - |y||\leq|x - y| $$

I can see obviously that  $ ||x| - |y||\le |x|-|y|.$ I just can't figure this one out.

Comment: Is your inequality correct? What if $x=-1$ and $y=2$?

Comment: $x=1,y=-1$ obviously is not true

Comment: Something's wrong: your claim is false... For example, $|1+|(-1)||$ is not less-than-or-equal $|1+(-1)|=|0|=0$

Comment: @paulgarrett Im sorry guys I meant - sign instead of +

Comment: Lookup the [reverse triangle inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality#Reverse_triangle_inequality). Btw, both `obviously` claims are false.

Comment: In response to your edit, the inequality $|x-y| \leq |x|-|y|$ now fails, for instance with $x=1$ and $y=-1$.

Comment: This is true for norms as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Sketch**: Notice first that if you can show $|x| - |y| \leq |x-y|$ and $|y| - |x| \leq |x-y|$, then you're done. Also observe that these two inequalities are ultimately the same, up to relabelling so it suffices to show $|x| - |y| \leq |x-y|$. But now, rearrange this to $|x| \leq |y| + |x-y|$ which should hopefully look familiar to you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reverse Triangle Inequality Proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/127372/reverse-triangle-inequality-proof)