# Let $a,b,c,d\in\Bbb{R}$ such that $|c|\ne|d|$. Prove that $\frac{a+b}{c+d}\le\frac{|a|+|b|}{||c|-|d||}$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, real-numbers, absolute-value

I can figure that $a+b\le|a+b|\le|a|+|b|$ but I do not know how to deal with $||c|-|d||$

Comment: This question is missing context or other details: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes the source and motivation of the problem, your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level.

Answer (score 2):

It is the reversed triangle inequality. For $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$, we have that $||x| -|y|| \leq |x - y|$.

See this post:

[Reverse Triangle Inequality Proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/127372/reverse-triangle-inequality-proof)