# Vector subtraction proof

Tags: vectors

Prove for any vectors $\mathbf{a}$ and $\mathbf{b}$

(i) $|\mathbf{a}—\mathbf{b}|\ge|\mathbf{a}|—|\mathbf{b}|$

(ii) $|\mathbf{a} — \mathbf{b}|\ge |\mathbf{b}| — |\mathbf{a}|$

(iii) Deduce that $|\mathbf{a} — \mathbf{b}|\ge |\ |\mathbf{a}| — |\mathbf{b}|\ |$

I have drawn parallelograms for (i) and (ii) so I know what $|\mathbf{a} — \mathbf{b}|$ looks like but I cannot *prove* them.

I cannot even fathom out what (iii) *means*.

Comment: $(ii)$ seems to have an extra set of magnitudes, $a-|b|$ doesn’t make sense.

Comment: You should look up the reverse triangle inequality. There should be plenty of proofs. And the right side of part (iii) means the absolute value of $|a|-|b|$, since that is a real number. And as Michael Burr says, the left side of (ii) should be $|a-b|$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reverse Triangle Inequality Proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/127372/reverse-triangle-inequality-proof)

Comment: Thanks. I’ve edited out the mistake in (ii)

Comment: As a hint, if you don't wanna just read the proof, try proving $|a-b|+|b| \ge |a|$ for part (i), using the triangle inequality. For part (iii), remember that $|x| \le y \iff x\le y \wedge -x\le y$.

Comment: I cannot believe that the [earlier question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/127372/reverse-triangle-inequality-proof) attracted 89 votes and the answer 113.