# prove $|A+B|\geq|A|-|B|$

Tags: inequality

Here is what I tried: $-|A| \leq A \leq |A|$ and $-|B|\leq B \leq |B|$ and adding the two inequality to get $|A+B| \leq |A|+|B|$.

Comment: How about $|A| = |(A+B) - B| \le |A+B| + |-B| = |A+B| + |B|$

Comment: Do you want to prove $|A+B|\geq|A|-|B|$ (Title) or $|A+B|\leq|A|+|B|$ (Text) ?

Comment: Probably some clarification could be useful. What are $A$ and $B$ (real numbers, complex numbers, sets)? What does the symbol $|\cdot|$ denote? (If they are numbers, most likely it is absolute value. If they are sets, most likely it is the number of elements.)

Comment: If the question is about numbers, the this is very close to [reverse triangle inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality#Reverse_triangle_inequality). See this post: [Reverse Triangle Inequality Proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/127372) (and [other [questions linked there](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/127372)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$|A+B|+|B|=|A+B|+|-B|\ge|A+B+(-B)|=|A|$$

Answer (score 1):

If $A$ and $B$ are positve then the absolute value of their sum is greater then the difference $|A| - |B|$. Now, suppose $A$ positive and $B$ negative with $|A|>|B|$: in thos case we have $|A+B|=|B|$. From here it's very simple to show the inequality holds for any $A$ and $B$.