# Algebra, analysis and inequality signs involving modulus signs

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, absolute-value

How do you derive that 
| |x|-|y| |<= |x-y|

Comment: This is known as the reverse triangle inequality, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/127372/reverse-triangle-inequality-proof).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already have the triangle inequality -

$$ |x| = |x-y+y| \leq |x-y| + |y|. $$

Subtract from both sides to conclude that

$$ |x| - |y| \leq |x-y|. $$