# Prove the triangle inequality only using the inverse triangle inequality.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, normed-spaces

I know the easy way to show the inverse triangle inequality using the triangle inequality. As far as I‘m aware of the two are equivalent so I was wondering how to prove the triangle inequality using only the inverse triangle inequlality. I tried using cases and some substitutions but I didn‘t get far:/
Thanks for your help<3

Comment: $\|x\|=\|(x+y+(-y)\| \geq \|x+y\|-\|y\|$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://math.stackexchange.com/q/127372

Comment: @JitendraSingh: That question is the opposite of what's being asked here.

Comment: @HansLundmark well if OP will try to receive idea from the question then I feel he/she might be also to solve it

Comment: @JitendraSingh: Apparently not, since they already said “I know the easy way to show the inverse triangle inequality using the triangle inequality”, which is what that question was about. But never mind...